# Is it ok to access YouTube with the programming system as described in robots.txt?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm creating a BOT to access youtube regularly using python requests module.

youtube's terms and conditions state this:

Terms of Service : https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms&hl=en&gl=US

> You are not allowed to:
>   ~中略~
>   3. access the Service using any automated means (such as robots, botnets or scrapers) except (a) in the case of public search engines, in accordance with YouTube’s robots.txt file; or (b) with YouTube’s prior written permission;

I'm accessing a link in robots.txt that is not described by `Disallow:`

https://www.youtube.com/robots.txt

In this case, can we say that we are in compliance with the terms and conditions?

Comment: If your bot is part of a public search engine sounds should be ok.

Comment: How do I make my BOT part of a public search engine?
Is it okay to use python's requests module to get it?

Comment: Thank you for reworking the question, Bryan!